# Check if substring from column exists inside string in another table column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have two tables, firstone **identifiants**, which has **id** column as below :
[image]

second table **informations**, which has **information id** column as below:

[image]

I added a custom column **check** in **identifiants** table to check if **id** exists (TRUE) or not (FALSE) in **information id** column in **informations** tabe:

but it give me for all ids FALSE even some of them exists in **information id**.

please what's the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=  Text.Contains(Text.Combine(informations[information id]," ") ,Text.From([id]))
```

EDIT

try

```
let CheckList=List.Combine(Table.AddColumn(informations, "Custom", each Text.SplitAny([information id],"/?!"))[Custom]),
...
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepName", "Custom", each if List.Count(List.Select(CheckList, (cat) => Text.EndsWith( cat, [id] )))=0 then false else true)
```

Comment: Excellent answer but it resolve only 50% of the problem, please have look to the edit post

Comment: I have an 352A5KL which it's a substring of other id 352A5KL75

So, to get TRUE the id 352A5KL  must be alone ended by space or / or ? or ! or it's in the end of the cell.

so id 352A5KL should be FALSE, because there is not cell in information id column that has this id.

Comment: Edited. Please stop changing requirements after posting question